# Linear equivalence of Divisors on a Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Studying algebraic geometry, while the abstract theory is pretty clear to me I often feel puzzled in practice. Here I am trying to understand linear equivalence of divisors in some practical situations. Consider the following example.

Let $S\subset\Bbb{P}^3$ be a smooth surface of degree $d\geq3$ and let $\ell\subset S$ be a line. A plane containing $\ell$ cuts on $S$ the divisor 
$$ H_0=\ell+C$$
where $C\subset S$ is a curve of degree $d-1$. Let $H$ be the divisor cut on $S$ by a generic plane. So $H$ cuts $\ell$ in one point. I am not sure about the following:

**Question:** why can we say that $H_0\sim H \ $ (linear equivalence) ?

This is then a nice example for showing that even the most simple divisor like $\ell$ can have negative self-intersection: if $H_0\sim H$ then
$$1=H\cdot\ell=H_0\cdot\ell=(\ell+C)\cdot\ell=\ell^2+C\cdot\ell=\ell^2+d-1 $$
Hence $\ell^2=2-d<0$.

Comment: The point is that restriction of divisors respects linear equivalence (as follows quickly from the definition). Any two planes in the ambient space $\mathbf{P}^3$ are linearly equivalent divisors (easy exercise!), so the same remains true when we restrict them to the surface $S$.

Comment: Here's something to ponder. Where did you use smoothness? Can we not have a ruled surface with degree $d\ge 3$?

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin, for any $d\geq3$ you could consider the smooth surface $S_d: \ x^d-y^d+z^d-w^d=0$ in $\Bbb{P}^3$, which contains the line $\ell: \ x-y=z-w=0$.

Comment: Thank you @AsalBeagDubh. That's clear now. I have a question: how would you compute the self-intersection $H_0^2$ without knowing $C^2$ (which would then follow) in this example?

Comment: Ruled surfaces have a line through *every* point!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you... I did't mean $S_d$ is ruled. I just meant that it serves as an example for this problem.

Comment: For your other question, the intersection of any two hyperplanes in $\mathbb P^3$ is, of course, a line. So $H_0.H_0$ is the intersection of $S$ with a generic line, i.e., $d$.

Comment: Right ... I'm asking what goes wrong on a ruled surface, where $\ell^2=0$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. What do you mean $\ell^2=0$ on a ruled surface? On the cubic $\ell^2=-1$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: no, a smooth surface of degree $\geq 3$ can never be ruled. One argument (maybe less than optimal) is this: a smooth cubic has Picard number 7, not 2, so is not ruled. For a smooth surface of degree $\geq 4$, adjunction tells you that its canonical divisor $K_S$ has nonvansihing global sections, so it cannot be ruled.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: but even suppose there were ruled surfaces of degree $\geq 3$, I'm not sure I would understand your objection. Being ruled is an intrinsic condition on the variety, not a condition on some projective embedding; why would it have to be true that the $\mathbf{P}^1$'s of the ruling were embedded as lines in $\mathbf{P}^3$? One could imagine something like a Hirzebruch surface where the ruling rational curves were embedded as some higher-degree curves, but still the embedded surface had a line on it. (Of course I just said that can't happen, but I hope my point still makes sense.)

Comment: @TedShifrin: apologies if I misunderstood your comments.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: My rhetorical questions were intended for the OP :) But I certainly meant geometrically ruled by lines, as opposed to an abstract $\mathbb P^1$-bundle. I wanted the OP to make sure he understood where smoothness is being used, as we can certainly take cones over curves of degree $\ge 3$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: yes, after I wrote my slew of comments I started to feel rather foolish. I left them there in case someone might find them useful. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Dear Heitor, the way you are learning algebraic geometry is exactly right: inventing concrete examples and making easy but not trivial calculations (and giving examples in the comments). Bravo, +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Turning my comment into an answer...) The point is that restriction of divisors respects linear equivalence (as follows quickly from the definition). Any two planes in the ambient space $\mathbf{P}^3$ are linearly equivalent divisors (easy exercise!), so the same remains true when we restrict them to the surface $S$.